# How to store data in an array that is stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, postman

Following is my problem:

I am testing a system now, that has multiple ID's in every request. There are 2 ID's I want to store in an array and let them run again a response later.

Following is the Body I recieve

```
{
"id" = 1234;
"Name" = "Meier"
}
```

So, I store the ID normally with

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ID", body.id);
```

with that I can store 1 ID in the variable, but can't put a second one in it. For that I would have to duplicate the request, set a second variable, change code everytime the needed cases are changed.

What I want to know now is: How can I store multiple ID's in a Environment Variable to compare them with a response at the end of the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with postman, but if I'm understanding correctly and you want to store up the Id's from the response then you could use something like -

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var storedIds = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("ID");

if(storedIds) {
    storedIds.push(body.id)
} else {
    storedIds = [body.id]
}

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ID", storedIds);
```

**Edit**

From my own googling, it appears you cannot store arrays in environment variables in postman. Therefore you could try doing something like this -

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var storedIds = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("ID");

if (storedIds) {
    storedIds = storedIds.concat(',' + body.id)
} else {
    storedIds = body.id
}

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ID", storedIds);
```

Then when you want to read it back out to loop over it or whatever you want to do you can use

```
var idsArray = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("ID").split(',')
```

which will split the string up to give you an array.

Comment: That's a nice way to do. If I run this code the first time, everything runs fine. but if I run it the second time I get an error "storeIDs.push is not a function"

Comment: I did some googling, looks like you can't store arrays directly in the postman environment variables. Please see updated answer.